# Why is nginx running although it's not installed?

Tags: windows-10, nginx

I'm on Windows 10 Home, 64-bit. I see in Task Manager that nginx (32-bit) is running. But I've never installed it.

See the following screenshots:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/DN2eT]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/DN2eT]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/DN2eT]

The nginx processes are in Task Manager, there's no nginx in Programs and Features, nor is there a service I can shut off.

Anyone know what this is, & how I can disable it?

Comment: go to details tab and activate commandline to see where nginx is started from

Comment: Hey thanks- that answered my question. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/ezeaYus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In taskmanager go to the `Details` tab, make a right click on the header and click on `select columns` and activate the `command line`:

[image]

Now you can easily see where the ngix is started from and which program bundled it.